# GCP Bigquery - Time Travel - How to disable it completely?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Just created a new dataset, and had a choice of setting the time travel window somewhere between 2 and 7 days.

We're using the physical storage billing model, and I would like to disable time travel completely. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, BigQuery time-travel cannot be disabled. You can [set it to the minimum 2 days](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-datasets#update_time_travel_windows) but you cannot turn it off completely. The underlying tech supports a bit more (e.g.  versioning with long running transactions) than just letting users query data at some point-in-time in the past so this is not something that's trivial to disable completely.